# asp.net WebApi 2 routing query string json with route parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

How can i implement the following routing scheme

```
http://localhost/vitualdir/prefix/{id}/methodname?{encoded json defenition of object}
```

using asp.net webapi 2 route attributes ?
My suggestions are :

firstly: add     `[RoutePrefix("prefix")]` to controller

secondly : implement the following defenition:

```
  [Route("~/{id}/methodname")]
  [HttpGet]
  public async Task<IHttpActionResult> methodname([FromUri] JsonObjectFromUri object, int id)
  {
```

But that code is not working as i want. Could you help me with it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'~' in the Route specified on an Action, overrides the Route prefix.

Try removing it. It should work.

Refer http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#prefixes

eg.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace MvcApplication2.Controllers
{
    public class TestClass
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }

    [RoutePrefix("prefix")]
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/values
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        [Route("{id}/methodname")]
        public string Get(int id, [FromUri] TestClass objectFromUri)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/values
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/values/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/values/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Now if you pass the Properties in the TestClass as url parameters, WebAPI will automatically bind them to the objectFromUri object.

http://localhost:39200/prefix/1/methodname?name=ram&age=10

Comment: I understand, thanks, but how can i take a json object from query string ?